# Acting to a transactions as soon as they are done

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, etherscan

My app requires to act to paid transactions in a matter of seconds. In a worst case scenario it could be few minutes.

Problem is that my geth chain is never at the point where Etherscan chain is. It's tens of minutes or even hours away. So when I get a block where transaction was made user could've asked for a refund by that time.

My question is how do you make your chain as close to Etherscan's. Is it even possible with geth? If not, how Etherscan does it and what are alternatives to my problem?

Comment: One possible cause is your server configuration is not enough to run geth. To sync mainnet in fast mode I'd suggest a large SSD with at least 100Gb, 8Gb of RAM and 2 cores.